# send new post notification to an email address stored in a custom field value

Tags: notifications

I need to send the WordPress new post notification to an email address stored in a custom field value.

I know how to get other meta data from the db using `get_the_author_meta`. What I do not know is where the changes have to be done in WordPress send mail trigger.

Answer (score 1):

I think this would be possible using the wp_mail() function (https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_mail/) alongside the `publish_post` action.

In fact, the publish_post action codex page has an example:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/publish_post

```
function post_published_notification( $ID, $post ) {
    $author = $post->post_author; /* Post author ID. */
    $name = get_the_author_meta( 'display_name', $author );
    $email = get_the_author_meta( 'user_email', $author );
    $title = $post->post_title;
    $permalink = get_permalink( $ID );
    $edit = get_edit_post_link( $ID, '' );
    $to[] = sprintf( '%s <%s>', $name, $email );
    $subject = sprintf( 'Published: %s', $title );
    $message = sprintf ('Congratulations, %s! Your article “%s” has been published.' . "\n\n", $name, $title );
    $message .= sprintf( 'View: %s', $permalink );
    $headers[] = '';
    wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers );
}
add_action( 'publish_post', 'post_published_notification', 10, 2 );
```

This could be modified to get the email address from a custom field.